# Scraping images related to a specific content in websites

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I have a list of websites and I would need to collect images possibly related to a specific article/news. 
For example:

Link: `https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/34893228`
News I am interesting in begins with: *Manchester United manager Louis van Gaal confirms he wants to bring Cristiano Ronaldo back to Old Trafford.*

Link: `https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/34923104`
News begins with: *BBC Sport looks at the best quotes from legendary Manchester United wingers George Best and Cristiano Ronaldo.*

I would need to get all the images related to those news. 
I specified the news beginning because sometimes in the same page there can be other articles/news that we are not interested in.

I have tried as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.core.display import HTML

df = pd.DataFrame({'Website': ['https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/34893228', 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/34923104']})

img=[]
for x in df.Website:
    print(x)
    html = urlopen(x)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    images = bs.find_all('img', {})
    for image in images: 
        print(image['src']+'\n')
        img.append(image['src'])

print(img)

def path_to_image_html(path):
    return '<img src="'+ path + '" width="60" >'

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)

HTML(df.to_html(escape=False ,formatters=dict(image=path_to_image_html)))
```

The code does not work. What I am trying to do there is to get all the images and try to store them as small pictures to include in the dataframe/dataset. The images should be stored in the same row of the website which are taken from. 
I do not know how to include the text as input/search to do on the webpage. With two links it would be easy, but unfortunately I have a dataset of thousands link to scrape.

I hope you could help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a simple image source description, you can get it with the following code; if you look at the website source, the image source is complex. You will need the corresponding code. I can only help you so far.

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from IPython.core.display import HTML

df = pd.DataFrame(index=[], columns=['Website', 'contents'])

Website = ['https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/34893228', 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/34923104']
loc = 0
for x in Website:
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(x)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    txts = bs.find_all('div', attrs={'id': 'story-body'})
    for i, txt in enumerate(txts):
        df.loc[i+loc,['Website']] = x
        df.loc[i+loc,['contents']] = txt.text.replace('\n', '')
    loc += 1 
    #print(i, x, txt.text.replace('\n', ''))

df.to_html('bbc.html', escape=False)
```

Comment: Thank you r.beginners. your code ids not taking into account the part of text. do you know iif it would be impossible to scrape only that part?  cannot go to visit each url, as I have thousands of them

Comment: Was the intent of the question a text collection? The method is the same, just specify the name of the class that contains the text you want to get. The class name of the text you want to get is different for each site, so you need to put the class name into the list or something. I forgot to write this. Replaced the code in the answer.